# Regexp dash or point

Tags: php, regex, image, preg-match

I need to match a part of filename on image files.
i have 2 type of its :

img000-size.jpg
img000.jpg

How can i only match img000 ?

PS : Can i get php code with preg_match please?
Thanks

Comment: *Can i get php code with [...]?* No. Show us what you've try first, where you failed and then we'll help you :)

Comment: That [tool](https://regex101.com/) should help you. :)

Comment: My problem is I need to get the filename without size or extension but I don't know how to use regular expressions. I scan my directory and get a list with product image with different size : 
chainsaw-large.jpg
chainsaw-medium.jpg
chainsaw-small.jpg 
chainsaw.jpg (original)

I need to split product name and size then copy this images into my prestashop image folder with a specific pattern : prduct_imageid_size.extension.

Here is what i try :
http://regexr.com/3dk19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let me help you...

regex: `/(\w+)(?:-\w+)?\.jpg/i`

data: `477547755-large.jpg`

match: `477547755`

I match a word character between 1 and unlimited times, than optionally a minus with again a word character and then the extension.
**notice: you have to escape the dot at the extension cause it will be interpreted as 'any char'**

description:

```
    1st Capturing group (\w+)
        \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    (?:-\w+)? Non-capturing group
        Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        - matches the character - literally
        \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    \. matches the character . literally
    jpg matches the characters jpg literally (case insensitive)
    i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

### REGEX101

Comment: Awesome, this works fine!!